# ASP.NET SqlDataSource parameter declaration in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters, code-behind, sqldatasource

I'm implementing SqlDataSource in code behind. Here is my code:

```
var sqlDataSource = new SqlDataSource
                                {
                                    ConnectionString = _constr,
                                    SelectCommand =
                                        "SELECT One, Two FROM Foo WHERE (One = @One) AND (Two = @Two)"
                                };
```

How to declare parameters and attribute them values in code behind? I've tried to do something like this: 
sqlDataSource.SelectParameteres.Add("@One", "value"); 
etc. but it thrown execute scalar error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
sqlDataSource.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("One", System.TypeCode.Int32, recordNo))
```